# Build error in visual studio with angular 2 typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015

i am using **typescript 2.0.2** and latest gulp script version .
after build from visual studio (using VS 2015 with .net core) generating these error 
[image]

please suggest some solution.

Comment: sorry your question is ot on SO but maybe you don't exclude the d.ts from compilation, take a look to your ts.config

Comment: "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/index",
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
anything else to do @infer-on

Comment: right, but you can understand that we can't play with screenshot, best luck

Comment: [lconfiguration files check here](https://github.com/nitinscorpion/Angular2) 

u can check my config file and please give me some +ve solution .. – @Infer-on